# Java Junit Repeatedtest fails with multithread code

Tags: java, junit

I have an task to solve, it's about testing a code that creates new thread for each invoke of one of it's methods

So here is main class

```
public class Radar {

    private static final int ROCKET_COUNT = 10;
    private PatriotBattery battery;

    public Radar(PatriotBattery battery) {
        this.battery = battery;
    }

    public void notice(Scud enemyMissle) throws InterruptedException {
        launchPatriot(enemyMissle, ROCKET_COUNT);
    }

    private void launchPatriot(Scud enemyMissle, int rocketCount) throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable launchPatriotTask = () -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < rocketCount; i++) {
                battery.launchPatriot(enemyMissle);
            }
        };

        Thread launchingThread = new Thread(launchPatriotTask);
        launchingThread.start();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public interface PatriotBattery {

    void launchPatriot(Scud enemyMissle);
}
```

And test class

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RadarTest {

    @Mock
    private PatriotBattery batteryMock;


    @RepeatedTest(10)
    void launchPatriotOnceWhenNoticesAScudMissle() throws InterruptedException {
        Radar radar = new Radar(batteryMock);
        Scud enemyMissle = new Scud();
        radar.notice(enemyMissle);
        verify(batteryMock).launchPatriot(enemyMissle);
    }

}
```

So far test passes when runned as single test (@Test), but when using ReapeatedTest it fails sometimes, as far as i have get to know testing multithread code can be complicated, but as main class is fairly simple with isolating code should pass tests, yet I am not sure how to refractor, if anyone have an idea what can be changed in order to make tests pass

Comment: what do you see in console, what are errors presented on failing test?

Comment: Test is checking if Interface method is used at least once so the error is that that method was used 0 times

Answer (score 0):

You can change the method notice() to return the launchingThread, and wait for it to finish in the test.

Or you can use https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility in your test.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest soulution i have found for my question is to use
ExecutorService. newDirectExecutorService from MoreExecutors to execute runnable instead of creating thread and starting it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).